# I've added frame grabs to give a good flavour of what the film is all about. (what is 'frame grabs'?)

Tags: vocabulary

> I've added frame grabs to give a good flavour of what the film is all about.

I think 'frame grabs' are used in a movie or television or graphics industry.

What exactly do 'frame grabs' mean?

Comment: A "frame grab" is a screen capture of a single frame from a movie, a single still image taken from a movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When films ('movies') were first made, they were made by using a camera which took still photographs very fast (24 each second) on a long strip of photographic 'film' (hence the name). The finished film was projected on a screen at the same rate of 24 pictures per second. People's brains are fooled into 'seeing' movement when pictures are shown very quickly.

When you look at the actual film, the individual pictures look like they are in black frames.

Here are three frames:

[image]

Later inventions such as television, digital video, etc, still work by showing still images very quickly, and they are still called 'frames' for historical reasons. When working with digital or other electronic video material (e.g. analog videotape), it is possible to extract ('grab') an individual frame. Such an image can be called a 'frame grab'.

A frame grab from that movie would look like this

[image]